# Targeting the specific link that the user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page full of different links that each have a class of `.post-link`.

In the following function, I'd like the line `$(this).html('loading...');` to target the specific `.post-link` div that is clicked. How would I go about achieving this? I feel I should create some sort of variable but I'm a bit lost. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('.post-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl;

    function projectShow() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: ajaxURL,
            data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');
                $(this).html('loading...');                     <--line in question
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#project-container').html(response);
                $('.post-container').addClass('fadeInUp');
                $('.close-button').addClass('fadeOutDown');
                $('#project-wrapper .entry-title').shuffleLetters();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Edit**

Here is how my HTML is set up:

`<a class="post-link"><img src="image.jpg"></a>`

Using Alexander's solution, the "loading..." text shows up like this:

`<a class="post-link"><img src="image.jpg">loading...</img></a>`

Is there a way to make it show like this?

`<a class="post-link"><span>loading...</span><img src="image.jpg"></img></a>`

Of course given that I wrap the text in `span` tags?

**Update**

```
$('.post-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var post_id = $(this).attr('rel'),
        ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl;

    function projectShow() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: ajaxURL,
            data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');
                $('<span class="loading">loading...</span>').insertBefore($(e.currentTarget).find('img'));
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('.loading').remove();
                $('#project-container').html(response);
                $('.post-container').addClass('fadeInUp');
                $('.close-button').addClass('fadeOutDown');
                $('#project-wrapper .entry-title').shuffleLetters();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() != 0) {
        projectShow();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop : 0
        },100);
    } else {
        projectShow();
    }
});
```

Comment: Side-note; You have a return false inside the `success:` handler. Return values there will not do anything.

Comment: Another side-note: Where is the code calling `projectShow`? Declaring it over and over inside a click handler is "not right" :)

Comment: Your HTML here implies that you have `.post-link` on the `A` tag, but in the comments you say that it's an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$('<span>loading...</span>').insertBefore($(e.currentTarget).find('img'));
```

or

```
$(e.currentTarget).prepend('<span>Loading</span>');
```

because `this` in `beforeSend` does not refer to element

Comment: What's wrong with the simpler `$(e.target).prepend()`?

Comment: Just one question: My function works in a way that if the user has scrolled the page at all, it first scrolls the page up and then fires the function. I would like the page to scroll up only after the `response` has been loaded. As of now, it scrolls up before the loading text has a chance to go away. Is there a way to set some kind of a delay? I added the full code above.

Comment: @J82 as I understood you want do something like this http://jsbin.com/paqope/1/edit?js

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
$('.post-link').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
// set a variable as a reference to 'this'
// prefixing variables containing jquery object with a '$' 
// as an easy way to spot them in your code

var $self = $(this),
    post_id = $(this).attr('rel'),
    ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl;

function projectShow() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');



            $self.html('loading...');
            // use if .post-link is a text element

            $self.prepend('<span>loading...</span>') 
            // if your .post-link is an image                


        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#project-container').html(response);
            $('.post-container').addClass('fadeInUp');
            $('.close-button').addClass('fadeOutDown');
            $('#project-wrapper .entry-title').shuffleLetters();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Although Alexander's answer is better as long as you don't override/re-declare the `e`

Comment: Simple standard approach. (I am concerned about the `img` you may be erasing though - see the notes).

Comment: Using a locally scoped var is a standard way of retaining scope and will work on all browsers. +1

Comment: Done, also left the original one in with a usage notice, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In browsers which support ES5 (IE >= 9), you can simply use `.bind(this)` to get context.

```
beforeSend: (function() {
    $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');
    $(this).prepend('<span>loading...</span>');                     
}).bind(this),
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer.

Comment: See the updated notes, .post-link is an image, so you wouldn't want to use '.html()' on it

Comment: @Killah: Since when is a IE9+ only answer "the best answer"? Any of the ones using a local variable are preferable to this one as they will work on all browsers.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Wow, there is actually someone that cares about IE8? Please don't tell me IE6/7 too. No wonder browsing the web is starting to require more and more horse power every year, with all those _"local variable here, local variable there, yeah! works on IE6!"_ types.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Any _professional_ will _help the share hit 0%_ by *not supporting* them. They need to die and as long as you support them someone may not have a reason to upgrade / switch. That 10% of the visitors (usually much less on websites I manage) is not worth keeping this old crap alive. And the easier way to kind-of support them is to drop the fancy stuff (actually just don't add it - progressive enchancement).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I'm in the business world. About the banks, from my experience if you show the managers a very good looking, shiny and fancy app on a new browser and the degraded version on their old IE6 side-by-side they will at least think about upgrading (and usually the shiny wins, at least in the cases I had). If not the laziness of both developers and IT people we would have 100% standard compliant browsers years ago. Also I think we are getting a bit off topic here, let's stop at the point that there are many different scenarios and there isn't "one-to-rule-them-all" principle there.

Answer (score 0):

You may have overcomplicated it a bit. Why do it in `beforeSend`? Just do it like this:

```
$('.post-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
    var ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl;

    // do it here:
    $('#project-wrapper').addClass('activated');
    $(this).find('img').before('<span>loading...</span>');

    function projectShow() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            url: ajaxURL,
            data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#project-container').html(response);
                $('.post-container').addClass('fadeInUp');
                $('.close-button').addClass('fadeOutDown');
                $('#project-wrapper .entry-title').shuffleLetters();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // I guess you are calling projectShow() somewhere in here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code

```js
$(this).parent('.post-link').html('loading....');
```

Comment: And where exactly would you suggest this code be inserted? `this` will not be a child of `.post-link` inside `beforeSend`.